# Disable prebuilt Razor UI pages after scaffolding identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In VS2022, I started a new Razor page project with "Individual Accounts" selected as authenization type.  I found that there are no identity-related code available for customization because they are prebuilt using the Razor UI. I want to customize the pages and so I generated the pages by the method suggested as below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1

After that, I wanted to disable the registration page after creating my admin account. I selected "Exclude from project" to Register.chtml as shown below.

[image]

Surprisingly, I found that the prebuilt Razor UI pages are automatically used when the generated pages are excluded(I can still access and use the url /Identity/Account/Register).  How can I disable the prebuilt Razor UI pages?

Comment: Hi @newcoder, although you do not choose the Register.cshtml, the Identity dll file still contains such page. You can custom a middleware to return 404 when the url is `/Identity/Account/Register`, or you can just customize the Register.cshtml.cs file to return NotFound() in page handler.

Comment: May I know how to implement the middleware?  For example, disable some urls by routing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `app.Map` middleware like below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.Map("/Identity/Account/Register", HandleRequest);
    app.Map("/Identity/Account/Login", HandleRequest);

    static void HandleRequest(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("404 Not Found");
        });
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want.  But your code have 2 issues:
1. level1App.Run(async context => , which lead to a warning saying that lacking await operator and would run synchronously
2. Do I need to I repeat the app.Map() code for each url I want to block?

Comment: 1. This warning is inevitable because Run method must use async delegate but HttpContext does not contains async method used to set Status Code. 2. You can move `.Run()` method outside and reuse it in different `app.Map()`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi @newcoder, pls check my updated answer.

Comment: That is perfect,  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you include the UI package, you opt in to using all of it. You can selectively disable pages by scaffolding them and then returning a `NotFoundResult` from both the `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods, but that can be laborious. You can also use Authorization to prevent access to pages or folders by specifying an authorization policy that is never applied to users, or a non-existent role, for example:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Does Not Exist")]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
   ...
```

Or, if you no longer need the Identity UI at all, uninstall the package from your application.